# How do I exit a while loop from a keypress without using KeyboardInterrupt? [python]

Tags: python, keyboard

I am making a timer that beeps every x seconds but the timer restarts during a certain keypress.
The first part of the code gets the timer to start.
Then it goes into a while loop for the timer. I want to interrupt the loop without pressing keyboard interrupt but rather another key.

Any help?Here is the code below

```
import time, winsound, keyboard
x = 0
while x == 0:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(','):
        x = x+1
while True:
    try:
        while x==1:
            for i in range(29):
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i)
                if i == 28:
                    winsound.Beep(300,250)
    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        continue
```

Comment: During the inner timer loop, test for your exit condition, then use a 'break' command if met. It will exit that inner loop to the one it is nested in (without quitting the program.) A better method would be to use an actual timer rather than a series of 29 one-second sleeps. Then your main cycle can continue to loop, checking for keyboard input until x seconds have elapsed, at which point the beep is sounded. If the exit key is pressed, handle as you wish.

Comment: how do i test for the exit condition?

Comment: I'm willing to help if I can. I'm at a disadvantage because I am not familiar with the keyboard mod, but the principle should be the same. I will cook up an example for you and post it here. In the mean time, maybe someone who knows the ins and outs of the keyboard mod will provide an working example using that mod for you. Check back here in a day or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example I promised you.

I did not need to import any mods for this program, but I believe the *msvcrt* mod that I use to control keyboard input is Windows specific. Be that as it may; even though we use different methods to control keyboard input, I hope you will see how your stopwatch can be controlled by key presses while a main program repeatedly loops and handles keyboard input.

```
import time     # Contains the time.time() method.
import winsound # Handle sounds.
import msvcrt   # Has Terminal Window Input methods 
# ===========================================
# -------------------------------------------
# --              Kbfunc()                 --
# Returns ascii values for those keys that
# have values, or zero if not.
def kbfunc():
    return ord(msvcrt.getch()) if msvcrt.kbhit() else 0
# -------------------------------------------
# --           Get_Duration()              --
# Gets the time duration for the stopwatch.
def get_duration():
    value = input("\n How long do you want the timer to run? ")
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except:
        print("\n\t** Fatal Error: **\n Float or Integer Value Expected.\n")
        exit()
    return value
# ===========================================
#                   Body    
# ===========================================
# To keep the program as simple as possible, we will only use
# standard ascii characters. All special keys and non-printable
# keys will be ignored. The one exception will be the
# carriage return key, chr(13).
# Because we are not trapping special keys such as the
# function keys, many will produce output that looks like
# standard ascii characters. (The [F1] key, for example,
# shares a base character code with the simicolon.)

valid_keys = [] # Declare our valid key list.
for char in range(32,127):  # Create a list of acceptable characters that
    valid_keys.append(char) # the user can type on the keyboard.
valid_keys.append(13)       # Include the carriage return.

# ------------------------------------------
duration = 0
duration = get_duration()

print("="*60)
print(" Stopwatch will beep every",duration,"seconds.")
print(" Press [!] to turn Stopwatch OFF.")
print(" Press [,] to turn Stopwatch ON.")
print(" Press [@] to quit program.")
print("="*60)
print("\n Type Something:")
print("\n >> ",end="",flush = True)

run_cycle = True # Run the program until user says quit.
stopwatch = True # Turn the stopwatch ON.
T0 = time.time() # Get the time the stopwatch started running.

while run_cycle == True:
    # ------
    if stopwatch == True and time.time()-T0 > duration: # When the duration
        winsound.Beep(700,300)  # is over, sound the beep and then
        T0 = time.time()          # reset the timer.
    # -----
    key = kbfunc()
    if key == 0:continue # If no key was pressed, go back to start of loop.    
    
    if key in valid_keys: # If the user's key press is in our list..
        
        if key == ord(","): # A comma means to restart the timer.
            duration = get_duration()         # Comment line to use old duration.
            print(" >> ",end="",flush = True) # Comment line to use old duration.
            t0 = time.time()
            stopwatch = True
            continue # Remove if you want the ',' char to be printed.
        
        elif key == ord("!"): # An exclamation mark means to stop the timer.")
            stopwatch = False
            continue # Remove if you want the "!" to print.
        
        elif key == ord("@"):  # An At sign means to quit the program.
             print("\n\n Program Ended at User's Request.\n ",end="")
             run_cycle = False # This will cause our main loop to exit.
             continue # Loop back to beginning so that the at sign
                      # is not printed after user said to quit.
             
        elif key == 13: # The carriage return means to drop down to a new line.
            print("\n >> ",end="",flush = True)
            continue
             
        print(chr(key),end="",flush = True) # Print the (valid) character. 
        # Keys that are not in our list are simply ignored.
```

Comment: Hey. First thanks for all this work. It really means a lot. But I am having a real hard time navigating some of this. So I would prefer that I use printable characters, I ideally want to restart the time by pressing ',' on the keyboard. And also, I don't want the timer to turn off. So when i tell the stopwatch to get going for 4 seconds, i want it to beep every 4 seconds until I turn it off. I tried playing around with your code but it seems that it keeps turning off the timer and when I remove 'stopwatch = false' it just keeps beeping. Any help?

Comment: Hi Sepher. All of the things you mention are easy changes to the code, but I'm afraid that we now are straying quite far from the reason Stack Overflow exists. Stack Overflow is intended to a provide users with answers to very specific questions about Python programing, not to write the programs themselves. Each thread should contain a single, well-defined question for others (such as myself) to answer. My example is intended to demonstrate how to control program flow using keypresses and it does so. The rest, I am afraid, is up to you. Python is worth learning. My hope is to give you a start.

Comment: Normally, if someone on Stack Overflow answers your original question and you have another question to ask (which has not already been asked and answered in the past) you should start a new thread using that question. You risk getting down-voted or even having your thread deleted by a moderator if it strays too far from Stack Overflows purpose for existing. That is the risk we face now. Still, you are a new user and I will hazard to make an exception just this one time to help you out, provided you understand that the sort of help you are now seeking is better suited to other sites. Agreed?

Comment: Gotcha. Agreed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Very good. Then I will modify the example code I have already posted to meet your needs and (hopefully) squeak past the mods as an answer to your original question. Check back in a bit.

Comment: The modified example program is much simpler than the first version. I did away with the dictionary and gone to a list of valid keyboard characters. I have also done away with all special characters and non-printable characters except the carriage return. I hope this version will better answer you original question. Try your first run with a duration of 1 second and then try the controls to see how the program works. I hope this helps. Cheers Man!
-Science_1

Comment: Minor bug-fix and spelling corrections just made. -Sci_1

Comment: Just a bit of trouble with the controls. I don't think it is restarting the time when i press ',' on the keyboard. Seems to be the same issue I was having with my own code as well. Do the keypress work for you?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand what you wanted when you said "restart the time". The comma should restart the stopwatch (after it has been stopped with the exclamation mark.) Did you want it to ask you for a new duration?

Comment: I have added a couple of lines to the section that handles the comma key so that it now asks for the duration to use. See if this is the behavior that you wanted. If the comma key still does nothing on your machine, then we have equipment differences that I can't help you with. (Try using a different character instead of a comma?) I hope the change did the trick. Cheers!
-Science_1

Comment: Works! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to click on Accept Answer if you found my example helpful.